# how to assign values into NSString from database

Tags: nsstring, nsmutablearray, ios5.1

I am getting TEXT type data from sqlite database into an `NSMUtableArray` Then I assigned them to NSString variables in this way

`NSString *billname=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tempAyyar valueForkey:@"Bill_Name"]];`

but it assignes the value as ("Test Bill"). but I want to get it as Test Bill. how can I get the value as this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Calling -valueForKey: on an array is returning an array with the results by calling -valueForKey: on it's objects. The following is from the documentation:

```
Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects.
```

In short, you should check what objects are in the array (probably an NSDictionary, or something similar.)

```
//just a safety check: if there is at least 1 object
if([tempAyyar count] > 0) {
    //value is probably an NSDictionary (you should check yourself)
    id value = [tempAyyar objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* billname = [value valueForKey:@"Bill_Name"];

    //now the name Bill's name should show properly
    NSLog(@"Bill's name is %@", billname);
}
```

Maybe you need to access multiple objects in your array, then you should adjust the sample code I provided.